# Disabling 'ping' response on Linux VPS

Tags: centos, vps, ping

I have a openvz linux vps and am trying to disable requests to 'ping' to my VPS.
How can i do this?

Comment: I hope you're not doing this because of "security" - ICMP echo is harmless, useful as a diagnostic tool and as far as DDoS attack vectors go is one of the least effective.

Comment: On top, ICMP has a usefull side feature so you are efficiently sabotaging parts of the IP stack. You basically disable PathMTU functionality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use iptables rules to achieve this:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j DROP
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line to your init script for the network (the name depends on the distribution you use):

echo 1 >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all

This disables ping responses.

To reenable, use the following command:

echo 0 >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all

To make this permanent set the following into /etc/sysctl.conf (if you have such a file)

net.ipv4.conf.icmp_echo_ignore_all = 1

Answer (score 1):

Simplest method of disabling ping response is to add an entry in /etc/sysctl.conf file. If the Iptables flushes or stop server will start responding to ping responses again. I suggest the following entry in your /etc/sysctl.conf file

> net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all = 1

this will tell kernel to not respond any ping response, after this run sysctl -p on shell to implement the changes without reboot.

For more info please refer: http://www.trickylinux.net/disable-ping-response-linux/

Answer (score 0):

You need iptables (or something similar) that blocks ICMP.
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-iptables-9-allow-icmp-ping.html